# Power spectrum calculation for simple inflaton potential

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

I am trying to obtain an expression for the power spectrum $\Delta (k)$ of cosmological perturbations, see for example eqn (148) from the following [TASI lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5424).

Right now, I would like to use the fact that $\frac{ d^2 \Delta (k)}{(d \ln k)^2 } = \frac{d}{d \ln k} ( n_s - 1)$ to obtain an expression for $\Delta$ as a function of $k$.

Now I can express $n_s$, the spectral index, in terms of the slow roll parameters for a given scalar field $\phi$ and associated inflaton potential $V(\phi)$ (left unspecified):

$n_s = 1 + 2\eta -6 \varepsilon$

where, in fact, the slow roll parameters $\eta$ and $\varepsilon$ are to be evaluated at $\phi_N$, corresponding to the 60 e-folding time before the end of inflation.

With the help of the following equality $\frac{d}{d \ln k} = - M_p \frac{\sqrt(2 \varepsilon)}{1-\varepsilon} \frac{d}{d\phi}$

I can then write

$\frac{ d^2 \Delta (k)}{(d \ln k)^2 } = - M_p \frac{\sqrt(2 \varepsilon)}{1-\varepsilon} \frac{d}{d\phi} n_s(\phi) $

My question is twofold:

1. Upon taking the derivative of $n_s$ with respect to $\phi$, is it understood that the value of $\phi_N$ should be plugged in *after* the derivative is evaluated?
2. What about the slow roll parameter appearing in $ - M_p \frac{\sqrt(2 \varepsilon)}{1-\varepsilon} $, as those are also functions of $\phi$? I would basically end up with an expression that is a function of $\phi$ on the RHS. How to I turn this into something of the form given in eqn (148)? That is, as a power function of $k$ only?

Comment: $k$ is usually the wavenumber of the perturbations in $\phi$. And yes, the slow roll parameters are expressible as functions of $\phi$. The hard way to do this would be to isolate the perturbative components of $\phi$ and fourier transform them into k-space. However, there's a simple relation that Baumann shows for the horizon-crossing power spectrum of scalar perturbations

Comment: So my question is are you looking to find the power spectrum throughout inflation? Or only after horizon crossing?

Comment: Right, at horizon crossing, $k = a H$, with $a$ the scale factor and $H$ the Hubble constant. So does that mean that with this assumption one can get at equation (203)?

And, I guess I am interested in the result for after horizon crossing, yes.

Comment: Yes, that equation should easily come out of the woodwork

Comment: don't forget that $2\epsilon=\frac{\dot\phi^2}{H^2}$